# SqlAlchemy in threads in Twisted

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlalchemy, twisted

I'm building a Twisted application in Python 2.7 and am trying to use SqlAlchemy to interact with the database. I've got a working application that is leaking memory, and am not sure how to find the leaks. As a "maybe this is the problem" I'm asking if how I'm using SqlAlchemy might be the source of the leaks. I've written a decorator to create the sessions I use to interact with the database. The decorator is wrapped around a function that accepts the session as a parameter and is called in a thread like this:

```
@inlineCallbacks
def update_db(data)
    @db_scoped_session
    def process(session):
        # do SqlAlchemy work here

    # call process in thread
    result = yield threads.deferToThread(process)
defer.returnValue(result)
```

where process is the function wrapped by the decorator. Here is my decorator code that is creating the session:

```
def db_scoped_session(engine, auto_commit=True):
''' Decorator: creates a SQLAlchemy Scoped Session and passes it in to the 
method which can then pass it along to the code that
needs to operate with the db
Parameters:
  engine         a sqlalchemy configured engine to use
  auto_commit    if True, this will commit the session on successful 
                 completion (no exceptions), will otherwise rollback

                 if False, assume the wrapped function is doing the
                 commit
'''
assert engine is not None, "Must pass a valid engine parameter"
def decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        results = None
        db_sessionmaker = scoped_session(sessionmaker(expire_on_commit=True, bind=engine))
        db_session = db_sessionmaker()
        try:
            results = func(db_session, *args, **kwargs)
            # should we rollback for safety?
            if not auto_commit:
                db_session.rollback()
        except:
            db_session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            db_session.commit()
        return results
    return wrapper
return decorator
```

Does anyone see anything wrong with what I'm doing above?

Thanks in advance!
Doug